# How to drop rows with duplicates column values and the number of columns are not always fixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe and columns in that dataframe could be any number(2-50). for example it is 2 columns as below. I want to remove rows where site1 and site2 are same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[507814, 501972], [529389, 529389], [508110, 508161]], columns = ['site1', 'site2'])
```

[image: whole dataframe]

I want to drop rows with similar column values as below Expected Output:

[image]

```
df[df["site1"] != df["site2"]]
```

This can be done this this line, but as I do not have fix number of column and this piece is inside of loop i need a fastest way to do this

I appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more columns, you can use `set()` + `len()`:

```py
x = df[~df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)), axis=1).eq(1)]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    site1   site2
0  507814  501972
2  508110  508161
```

---

Edit: To specify columns:

```py
x = df[~df[["site1", "site2"]].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)), axis=1).eq(1)]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    site1   site2   site3
0  507814  501972  508284
2  508110  508161  508098
```

`df` used:

```
    site1   site2   site3
0  507814  501972  508284
1  529389  529389  508284
2  508110  508161  508098
```

Comment: This works pretty well with site 2. but if i try to do site 3 It doesn't work well. df = pd.DataFrame([[507814, 501972,508284], [529389, 529389,508284], [508110, 508161,508098]], columns = ['site1', 'site2','site3'])

Comment: I have number of columns inside of loop. so I used this. df = df[df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)), axis=1).eq(site)]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
df = df[df.nunique(axis=1) > 1]
```

Comment: This works pretty well with site 2. but if i try to do site 3 It doesn't work well. df = pd.DataFrame([[507814, 501972,508284], [529389, 529389,508284], [508110, 508161,508098]], columns = ['site1', 'site2','site3'])

Comment: what exactly do you want to do, do you want to remove the rows where all the values are equal, or is it the ones that at least two values are equal ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. This should work if all your site values are numbers.

```
df.loc[df.diff(axis=1).sum(axis=1).ne(0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, this filters the columns where `site1 == site2`:

```py
# first option
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x["site1"] == x["site2"], axis=1)]

# second option
df.query("site1 != site2")
```

All options give you:

```
    site1   site2
0   507814  501972
2   508110  508161
```

Comment: As I said earlier, I have don't have a fix number of columns. The above mentioned is just example. number of site can be any, and I need a common solution around it. Thanks